# How to convert int type number/letter to char and *char?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-ide

I am using LittleFS library and ESP32 on arduino IDE.
I am reading a file using the example readFile function of LittleFS but I am trying to convert it for my needs.
The text written to the file is of this form:
LettersAndNumbersMax30&LettersAndNumbersMax30&00&00&01&01

Seperated by &. 2 text values of max 30 characters and 4 integers.

I want to build:
char *mytest1 containing the first text
char *mytest2 containing the second text
int mytest3 containing the first integer  (2digits)
int mytest4 containing the second integer (2digits)
int mytest5 containing the third integer (2digits)
int mytest5 containing the forth integer (2digits)

file.read() returns and integer always. for example 38 for &.

```
void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

File file = fs.open(path);
if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
    Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
    return;
}

Serial.println("- read from file:");
while(file.available()){
    Serial.write(file.read());
  
}
file.close();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly straightforward.  Test each byte read and act accordingly.  Code below doesn't handle signs nor negative numbers.  It also doesn't check if there are only digits for integers in the file.

```
#include ....

struct record_t
{
   char myState1[31]; 
   char myState2[31]; 
   int  myState3;
   int  myState4;
   int  myState5;
   int  myState6;
};

record_t record;

bool readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path);

void setup()
{
    // ... 
}

void loop()
{
    //...
    if (readFile(/*...*/))
    {
        Serial.printf("file reads OK\r\n");
        //...
    }
}

bool readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path)
{
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);

    if (!file || file.isDirectory())
    {
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("- read from file:");
    int state = 0;
    int index = 0;

    // clear record.
    record.myState1[0] = 0;
    record.myState2[0] = 0;
    record.myState3 = 0;
    record.myState4 = 0;
    record.myState5 = 0;
    record.myState6 = 0;
 
    bool valid = false;
    for (int i = file.read(); i != -1; i = file.read())
    {
        char c = i & 0xFF; 
        Serial.write(c);    // file.read() returns an int, that's why     Serial.write()
                            //  was printing numbers.

        switch(state)
        {
        case 0:
            if (index > sizeof(record.myState1) - 1) // avoid buffer overflow
                index = sizeof(record.myState1) - 1;
            if (c != '&')
            {
                record.myState1[index++] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                record.myState1[index] = 0;
                ++state;
                index = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            if (index > sizeof(record.myState2) - 1) // avoid buffer overflow
                index = sizeof(record.myState2) - 1;
            if (c != '&')
            {
                record.myState2[index++] = c;
            }
            else
            {
                record.myState2[index] = 0;
                ++state;
                index = 0;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            if (c != '&')
                 record.myState3 = record.myState3 * 10 + (c - '0');
            else
                 ++state;
            break;

        case 3:
            if (c != '&')
                record.myState4 = record.myState4 * 10 + (c - '0');
            else
                ++state;
            break;

        case 4:
            if (c != '&')
                record.myState5 = record.myState5 * 10 + (c - '0');
            else
                ++state;
            break;

        case 5:
            valid = true;
            if (c != '&')
                record.myState6 = record.myState6 * 10 + (c - '0');
            else
                ++state;
            break;

        default:  // reaching here is an error condition?  You decide.
            return false;
        }
    }
    file.close();

    if (!valid)
    {
        // clear record.
        record.myState1[0] = 0;
        record.myState2[0] = 0;
        record.myState3 = 0;
        record.myState4 = 0;
        record.myState5 = 0;
        record.myState6 = 0;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, but i need to call a function of a class which accepts *char for the first two and integers for the last 4. Should i convert(and if yes, how?) the char mytest1 and char mytest2 to char * ? or shall we change the code to make them from the beginning char * so i can call the other function?

Comment: An char array will automatically decay to a `char*`...  This makes the syntax of caling your function as simple as : `YourFunction(record.myTest1); ` .   You do need to store the string somewhere, and it must have a terminating NULL byte,

Comment: so we have to put  the '\0' only to char* and not to char array (char xxx[100])

Comment: I change myState to mytest because it wouldn't compile and case1; to case1: however i cannot compile it. i put the stuck record and record_ t record  before setup() and i #include the functions.h which contains the readFile but it says: exit status 1
'record' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Declarations have to be in the right order for things to complie.  And record MUST be a global vartiable.

Comment: it worked now, needed to replace MyState with mytest because you did this typo, however code works great! amazing.  the way you wrote the code, the integers can be more than 2 digits right? because you split it by delimiter & and you parse it. is that correct?

Comment: Hi again, how could i modify this code to work for multiline file and make an array like record_t record[100] ? thanks

Comment: There is usually not enough space on arduinos to load an entire file at once...  Why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

file.read returns integer. So the integer is printed.

You to convert it to the string.

```
while(file.available()){
    char s[2] = {0};
    s[0] = file.read();
    Serial.write(s);
}
```

Comment: then if i have a char * myvar can use strncpy(myvar,s)?